# Build C++ project to include ALL msvc dlls

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a simple C++ program. I want to just build the exe and give it to a person on another complete non-development box. Is there a way to build such a simple, single-source file to an executable in Visual Studio without needing all the *crap* ? I have changed the program to compile in MT mode, instead of MTD which statically linked the msvcr.dll file, but now it is looking for msvcp.dll file. How can I compile so that my executable either 1) doesnt include all this junk or 2) statically links it all so that I have exactly one file to transfer to another Windows PC to run

Thanks

Comment: Do you compile your program in Debug or Release configuration?

Comment: Are you 100% certain you set it to "Multi-threaded" or "Multi-threaded Debug", and not "Multi-threaded DLL" or "Multi-threaded Debug DLL" ? (Remember to change the configuration for both Release and Debug builds)

Comment: @nos 100% certain. It was asking for msvcr100.dll before, after switch to Multi-threaded it asks for mscvp100.dll

Comment: Is this a MFC application ? you might need to alter settings to link to MFC statically too

Answer (score 2):

If compiling with /MT is requiring msvcr100.dll, something included in your application is probably trying to link with it, possibly a third party component. I would check any third party libraries and related.

MSVCP100.DLL is the C++ standard library. You might want to double check that it's not looking for MSVCP100D.DLL, which is the debug version; mixing release and debug mode libraries could cause this.

Answer (score 1):

MSVCRT100.DLL is the C run-time library, and MSVCP100.DLL is the C++ standard library. Both should go away if you build with /MT, in that case static versions of these libraries should have been used.

My guess is that you either did not fully rebuild your app after switching to /MT, or that one or more files in your project have custom settings that include /MD. You may want to open the properties dialog box on the page that shows the /MT and then click on all your source files one by one to verify that none of them still show /MD.